# Make SQL Server compact 4 data connection with Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-express, data-connections

I am trying to do a sql server compact 4 data connection with visual studo 2010 express but I have seen that it is not listed under data connection. Also SQL server compact toolbox here:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1
when I try to install its says it is not compatible with this version of visual studio (2010 express) so Is there a way to do a data connection to a sql server compact 4? Also servers browsers does not appear in visual studio 2010 express. I want to use and embedded sql server compact in my asp.net mvc4 web application without the need to install any sql server in the machine.

I know that with visual studio 2010 ultimate it is possible, sql server compact 4 data connection can be done and servers browser also appear under view menu. Also I am not sure if with other versions of visual studio 2010,p.e, professional it can be done as well or only with the ultimate.

In conclusion, I want to use sql server compact data connection with my visuals studio 2010 express, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you must you VS 2010 Visual Web Developer Express, and resolve any install isssues according to the blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx - you can also use the standalone version of the SQL Server Compact Toolbox to open 4.0 files.

Comment: Great! I have installed web platform installer, last version 4.6, and from there I can choose the packages commented in the link you provided then from visual studio 2010 express, when creating data connection, I can see lister Microsoft sql server compact 4.0 :) many thanks!!!